# Apple TestFlight Sign In Notifications/Background Update Issues

Tags: ios, testflight

Anyone using TestFlight on iOS devices noticing very recent (past week) issues with it?

On multiple of my devices I'm seeing frequent notifications with "To download the latest beta versions of your apps, sign in to TestFlight.". It seems to pop up by itself around once a day, and it will also pop up in place of a notification for an update to an app in TestFlight or in place of a background update, meaning there is no background TestFlight updates while plugged in when this happens. You can still Install/Manually update everything, its just the auto updates that don't work.

Testflight also doesn't really have its own sign in, it uses your app store login, and both are signed in when you check.

Anyone else noticing issues with TestFlight recently? Im assuming there is a problem on their back end, and I've seen a few others mention it, but not as much as I would have assumed. maybe its because manually initiated updates still work fine?

To Troubleshoot I have uninstalled TestFlight, signed out of the App Store, cleared out old remembered devices in TestFlight from another still logged in device, Restarted the device and reloged in/installed TestFlight.

The first time this was done a few days ago the problem seemed to have cleared, update notifications and background updates were working immediately again. But now its back again and repeating this doesnt seem to do it.